# Google Analytics - Different Source and Medium for the same Transaction ID

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using R's googleAnalyticsR package to get the google analytics data. My aim is to reach session and transaction specific information. My google analytics data retrieval code is

```
gadata <- google_analytics_3(id = ga_id,
                             start = "2018-08-21",
                             end = "2018-09-07",
                             metrics = c("transactions","transactionRevenue","bounceRate" ,"transactionShipping", "sessions", "itemQuantity", "uniquePurchases", "itemRevenue", "revenuePerUser", "transactionsPerUser"),
                     dimensions = c("source","medium","transactionId", "sessionsToTransaction", "daysToTransaction", "date","sessionDurationBucket"), 
                             max = 1000000, samplingLevel = "WALK")
```

The code is working. I am getting the results but there are some duplicated transactionId's with different sources and mediums. I do not know the cause of it. For instance,

```
source    medium     transactionId    sessionsToTransaction    daysToTransaction
 xx.com   referral       123                   1                      0 
 google   organic        123                   4                      17
```

I want to calculate the date of the first visit. I will subtract the value of the `daysToTransaction` from the transaction date. There are about 25 duplicated transationId's with the same form. They have one more source and medium with 1 as sessionsToTransaction value and 0 as daysToTransaction value. I think that this customer completed his purchase with referral from xx.com and he/she visited our website 17 days ago for the first time. But I am not sure since I am new to google analytics metrics/dimensions.

My questions are

- How should I interpret this output?
- Should I consider the row with
  the biggest value all the time?
- Is it ok to remove the row that has
  0 value in daysToTransaction?

Thanks.

Comment: How is transactionId defined in GA? What's the scope on it? What's the logic for updating this value to GA? Can you please clarify on the scope of all the custom dimensions that you have and comment on how the custom metrics are calculated?

Comment: Hello, transactionId is the ID of the sales in my case. When a customer finishes his/her shopping GA creates a transactionId and updates the database. Using transactionId I can reach further information about this customer. This link explains all dimensions https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets